# SQL Server Update nested hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I am trying to solve what I think is a nested recursion problem. I have a sample table like this:-

```
Employee    Manager     IsPartTime?
A           Null            0
B           A               1
C           B               1
D           C               0
E           B               0
```

It is simple Employee-Manager problem table with `IsPartTime` flag. Since a part time employee is not permanent, he can't be a Manager of any permanent employee. So, I need to update `D` & `E` employees to their resp. correct next level Manager in hierarchy. So, I am tying to achieve:-

```
Employee    Updated Manager    Old Manager
A               Null                -
B               A                   -
C               B                   -
D               A                   C
E               A                   B
```

I tried to create a temporary table using Recursive CTE, but the problem is I am getting only 1 level up but I need to traverse up until any Manager who is Permanent is found.

```
;WITH EmployeeCTE AS
    (
        SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerId
        FROM Employee
        where Manager in ('C', 'B')

        UNION ALL

        select e.EmployeeId, e.ManagerId
        from Employee e
        inner join EmployeeCTE  cc 
            on e.Manager = cc.Employee
    )
    select * from EmployeeCTE
```

Comment: To clarify one thing, why wouldn't Employee C be updated? The way I'm reading the data, C's manager is B and B is a PartTime employee.

Comment: Because C is part-time employee too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm correct in interpreting the data, here's what I've got:

```
-- first, establish the hierarchy and while doing that
-- add a hierarchyid column
with d as (select * from (
    values
        (1, 'A', Null, 0),
        (2, 'B', 'A',  1),
        (3, 'C', 'B',  1),
        (4, 'D', 'C',  0),
        (5, 'E', 'B',  0)
    ) as x(ID, Employee, Manager, IsPartTime)
)
, r as (
    select ID, Employee, Manager, IsPartTime, cast(concat('/', d.ID, '/') as varchar(max)) as h
    from d
    where Manager is null

    union all

    select child.ID, child.Employee, child.Manager, child.IsPartTime, cast(concat(parent.h, child.ID, '/') as varchar(max)) as h
    from r as parent
    join d as child
        on child.Manager = parent.Employee
)
select ID, Employee, Manager, IsPartTime, cast(h as hierarchyid) as h
into #t
from r;
```

With the hard part done, now we can look to see who needs to be update using the hierarchyid and a correlated subquery.

```
with u as (
    select *, (
        select top(1) Employee
        from #t as a
        -- this person is a subordinate of the person from the main table
        where t.h.IsDescendantOf(a.h) = 1 
            -- exclude the employee themselves from consideration
            and t.ID <> a.ID
            -- the manager needs to be full-time.
            and a.IsPartTime = 0
        order by a.h.GetLevel()
    ) as NewManager
    from #t as t
    where IsPartTime = 0
)
select *
from u
where Manager <> NewManager;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I didn't get what is `IsDescendantOf` & `GetLevel`? Are they separate functions? It will make solution very complex in that case. BTW, I have resolved my problem using a flag and `While` loop.

Comment: Hierarchyid is a built-in CLR data type. As such, it has methods which can be called against it. Both of those functions are such methods. As to complexity, most of that code was to structure the data in a way that lent itself to be easily queried. If you don't want to use it, it doesn't bother me; I got something out of the exercise either way.